# How can I convert a feather file to CSV using Python?

Tags: python, csv, feather

How to convert feather file into csv file using python?

I tried using feather module,  pyarrow.feather  I could only read it but I couldn't convert it to csv format.

```
# when using pandas
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_feather('coffee_ratings_full.feather')
```

I got this error=>

```
ArrowInvalid                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_26876/2731998856.py in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_feather('coffee_ratings_full.feather')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\feather_format.py in read_feather(path, columns, use_threads, storage_options)
    128     ) as handles:
    129 
--> 130         return feather.read_feather(
    131             handles.handle, columns=columns, use_threads=bool(use_threads)
    132         )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\feather.py in read_feather(source, columns, use_threads, memory_map, **kwargs)
    224         The contents of the Feather file as a pandas.DataFrame
    225     """
--> 226     return (read_table(
    227         source, columns=columns, memory_map=memory_map,
    228         use_threads=use_threads).to_pandas(use_threads=use_threads, **kwargs))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\feather.py in read_table(source, columns, memory_map, use_threads)
    250         The contents of the Feather file as a pyarrow.Table
    251     """
--> 252     reader = _feather.FeatherReader(
    253         source, use_memory_map=memory_map, use_threads=use_threads)
    254 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\_feather.pyx in pyarrow._feather.FeatherReader.__cinit__()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\error.pxi in pyarrow.lib.pyarrow_internal_check_status()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\error.pxi in pyarrow.lib.check_status()

ArrowInvalid: File is too small to be a well-formed file
```

Comment: Did you try [`df.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)?

Comment: after df = pd.read_feather('coffee_ratings_full.feather')? I got this error =>ArrowInvalid: File is too small to be a well-formed file

Comment: In your question you say you could read the file, but your comment suggests that you couldn't. It would help to (1) show the full traceback message as a separate code block in your question and (2) include an additional `df.to_csv(..._)` in the original example so we have all of the code.

Comment: The error suggests your feather file is bad which would be a problem with whatever wrote it. That may be the code we need to debug. How big is this file?

Comment: it's 777 kB , does that answer your question?

Comment: You can get this error if the feather file writer crashed somehow or didn't close properly and you have an unfinished file. You can also get it if the file is the wrong type (it would be worth looking at the first few lines to see if its looks like regular text - which would be bad). You can also get it if you have mismathed feather versions between writer and reader. You can check them both. Just guesses!

Comment: you were right, I think it crashed, I reuploaded the Feather file and then rerun the code with Pandas it could read it properly, thanks

Comment: I wrote an answer because I think its useful to note what this error text can mean.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the file is large, its still smaller than the feather headers claim it should be. That can happen if there was a problem writing or downloading the file. From the comments, that was the problem in this case. So, its not this code, but whatever wrote it in the first place.